# WiFi N Gigabit Router

Tags: router, wireless-networking, hardware-rec, 802.11n, gigabit-ethernet

I'm looking for a WiFi N Gigabit router.  I'll be using an iPod Touch 2G and a 2009 17" MacBook Pro over WiFi, and I need at least 4 gigabit ethernet ports plus a WAN port.

What do people recommend?

In particular, are there any compatibility issues between different WiFi N drafts that would limit the speed of the MacBook, and is it worth getting dual-band?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a Linksys WRT310N, which has 4 ports of Gig-E and Draft-N WiFi.  The antennae are internal, which looks nice.  It can run the open source firmwares like DD-WRT.  See [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linksys_WRT300N_series#WRT310N) for some details.

[image]

$95 from [Newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833124276)

Comment: Too bad WRT350N are no longer being sold on Newegg, it has much better coverage than this one. Still +1 for DD-WRT suggestion.

Comment: Be careful with what you buy.  Linksys regularly releases new revisions of existing products that have the same model number, but different hardware.  As such, not all versions of a particular model are supported by DD-WRT.

Answer (score 3):

Since your already going with Apple products, I would recommend the [Airport Extreme](http://www.apple.com/airportextreme/specs.html). A bit pricey but guaranteed to work with your MacBook and iPod Touch.

Also the [Time Capsule](http://www.apple.com/timecapsule/specs.html) is not a bad choice which also gives you the ability to use Time Machine.

Comment: I need four ports plus the WAN.

Comment: Fair enough. I forgot about the 3 ports only. However leaving the answer since it could still be an option.

Comment: whether it has 3 or 4 ports isn't an issue since you get splitters for next to nothing

Comment: well, if you really mean a _splitter_ that would be a horrible idea, because you can't split an ethernet signal. Now if you mean a _switch_ that is true, but still, next to nothing is not nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend a Time Capsule network with an Airport extreme and get that last last ethernet port.  This has the added benefit of supplying an audio output and a larger effective network area if your machines are spread apart.  It is an expensive solution for that last port . . . but it is very easy to manage from your mac.  I have this solution running in my house.  I have backups and a fast, reasonably secure network with remote speaker capability.  I'm considering putting one outside on the deck in a weather proof box to supply music outside . . .